# Showing $f\in\mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]:f'=0\Rightarrow\exists g\in\mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]:f=g^p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ denote the final field with $p^d$ elements and $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]$ denote the polynomial ring in $X$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$. How can we show $$f\in\mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]:f'=0\Rightarrow\exists g\in\mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]:f=g^p$$
The case $d=1$ is easy (since $a^p=a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{F}_p$) and also gives us the other direction. But what about $d\ge 2$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You need that if $a\in F_{p^d}$ then $(a^{p^{d-1}})^p = a^{p^d}=a$.

Comment: That's easy since the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}^*$ is cyclic with $|\mathbb{F}_{p^d}^*|=p^d-1$, $a$ is a $(p^d-1)$-th root of unity.

How does it help exactly?

Comment: Sorry, that's the extent of my hint. How did you easily show it with $d=1$?

Comment: What you need is that for any $a\in \mathbb F_{p^d}$, there is a $b\in \mathbb F_{p^d}$ such that $a=b^p$.

Comment: So, we can choose $$b=a^{p^{d-1}}$$ But again, how does it help exactly?

Comment: If $d=1$, then we can show $$f=\sum_{i=0}^na_iX^i\in\mathbb{F}_p[X]\Rightarrow f^p=\sum_{i=0}^na_iX^{ip}$$

Comment: Now you are confusing the $f$ in the original problem. The condition $f'=0$ means $f=\sum_{i=0}^i a_iX^{pi}$. Then you need to find $g$.

Comment: I'm not confusing the $f$ in the question. If $d=1$, then $f^p=f$. So, $f$ itself is the searched $g$.

Comment: No, $X^p\neq X$ in $F[X]$. They are equal as functions on $F_p$, but not as polynomials. So $f^p=f$ is not true in $F[x]$ except when $f\in F$.